# Android Newbie : couldn't connect to OpenWeatherMap properly

Tags: android, url, webserver, httpurlconnection, openweathermap

I am following the tutorials from Tutplus and youtube on Android WeatherApp creation. Please find my code below. I am trying to connect to OpenWeatherMap and get JSON weather data. Here are my problems:

1. Its not working.
2. Is this the right way to create the URL for accessing OpenWeatherMap.
3. When I registered with the OpenWeatherMap, it gave me a KEY. I am not sure what to do with that. I used it in my code, after getting the httpurlconnection from the server for setting "x-api-key". Don't know if its needed or am doing it
4. when i get the inputstream, the reader is null and  the application hangs after that.

Here is the code:

```
public class WeatherGrabber {

private static final String TAG = "WeatherGrabber";

private static final String CURRENT_WEATHER_URL = 
"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%s&mode=json";

private static BufferedReader reader;
private static final String my_key = "307ec986e69c22c9a24a1bcf9edd21ea";


public static String loadCurrentWeather(Context context, String city) {

    String data = null;

    try{

      URL web_url = new URL(String.format(CURRENT_WEATHER_URL, city) );

      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) 
                               web_url.openConnection();
        conn.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", my_key);


            reader = new BufferedReader(new
                      InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer();

            while((inputLine = reader.readLine() )!= null){

                json.append(inputLine).append("\n");

            }
            data = json.toString();



    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    return data;
}// end of loadCurrentWeather() method


}
```

Comment: Are you already read this tutorial? http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/build-weather-app-json-http-android.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't run network requests directly on the main thread. You need to use AsyncTask class to do this.

Create a class in you activity

```
private class LoadCurrentWeatherAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            //Call to your function here
            return loadCurrentWeather(MainActivity.this, "newyork");
        } catch (Exception e){
            return e.toString();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        //Do what ever you what with this output
        Log.d("data", s);

    }

}
```

Then call it inside your activity onCreate method

```
new LoadCurrentWeatherAsync().execute();
```

Also make sure that you have enabled the internet permissions in  AndroidManifest.xml . Inside the manifest tag insert

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2. It's ok
3. They use the api key to track whether request is from free or paid plan.
4. I suspect that's because you are sending the network request on main thread. Try the above code

Comment: Thank you very much. 4th point made the difference. The code is working now.